# Finding the nearest number to zero among $\sin1, \sin2, \sin3, \ldots, \sin n$ (in radians)

Tags: analysis

How can we find the nearest number to zero among
$$\sin1, \sin2, \sin3, \ldots, \sin n$$ (where $n$ is a natural number, and the functions are based on radians)?

Comment: I assume that you're excluding the trivial $\sin 0$?

Comment: @Dan The assumption is not necessary. The question is explicit with $1,2,3\dots n$

Comment: What about $n=314159265358979323846$? (In case you don't get it, it's $\pi \times 10^{\text{much}}$ :-) )

Comment: Well, you could specify any $\epsilon > 0$ and it will get that close eventually.  So, there is no closest for all of the natural numbers.  I think that the question is for a specific finite range.  This allows the simple boring solution of just checking the whole lot.

Comment: multiples of numerator of [convergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) of $\pi$. eg. $3,22,333,355,103993,104348,\ldots$. If you make a $xy$-plot for $( n, |\log|\sin n||) $, you will see a bunch of peaks at multiples of those $n$.

Comment: Sin0 is not our answer. Zero is not a natural number. Sin is periodic number

Comment: Are you asking about a finite $n$, or the whole set of natural numbers?

Comment: Dont mention that n is  finit  or not, it in the question. I

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}: \sin(\pi k) = 0$.  And it can be shown with the standard trig identities that $|\sin(\pi k + \epsilon) - \sin(\pi k)| = |\sin(\epsilon)| \le \epsilon$.  So, your question is equivalent to asking [for the best rational approximation of $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506435/best-possible-rational-approximation-of-pi).

If you're considering the domain $1 \le n \le 100$, then the optimum is $\sin 22 \approx -0.008851$, which is related to the familiar approximation $\pi \approx \frac{22}{7}$.

For $1 \le n \le 10^{6}$, the optimum is $\sin 833719 \approx 2.31\times10^{-6}$, related to the approximation $\pi \approx \frac{833719}{265381}$.

For any finite set of natural numbers $1 \le n \le N$, the optimum $n$ is [the numerator of a continued fraction convergent to $\pi$](https://oeis.org/A002485).  (Thanks to @RobertIsrael for the OEIS link.)

For the infinite set of natural numbers, there is no unique “nearest number to zero”, because for any rational approximation of $\pi$, there's always a better approximation with a higher numerator and denominator.  Thus, [the sine function is dense in $[-1, 1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1).

Comment: More specifically, it's asking for best approximations of the second kind. and these are the convergents of the continued fraction.  The numerators of the convergents of the continued fraction for $\pi$ are [OEIS sequence A002485](https://oeis.org/A002485).